# Interdependent Generic Classes?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, polymorphism, graph-theory

At the bottom of this post is an example of how a solution might look, although clearly the example is invalid because it used BaseNode and BaseEdge without providing types when inheriting.

I'm trying to create an abstract graph class, where both the node class and the edge class must also be abstract. Individual implementations of each class will add methods and properties as well as implementing abstract methods from the base classes.

I have an existing solution that merely uses the base types for everything, however I quickly found myself in a mess of casting.

Only the graph class must be publicly exposed, although the others can be, so solutions involving node and edge classes being nested within the graph class are acceptable.

Is there any way in which this can be structured such that all properties are of the proper types without expensive casts anywhere in the system? It's more important that implementing classes don't have to cast everywhere, but performance is definitely a concern in this case (it actually is) so I would rather avoid casting altogether.

```
abstract class Graph<TNode, TEdge>
    where TNode : BaseNode<TEdge>
    where TEdge : BaseEdge<TNode>
{
    TNode root;
    List<TNode> nodes;
    List<TEdge> edges;

    public abstract float process();
}

abstract class BaseNode<TEdge>
    // THIS HERE IS THE PROBLEM
    where TEdge : BaseEdge
{
    List<TEdge> inputs;

    public List<TEdge> Inputs
    {
        get
        {
            return inputs;
        }
    }

    public abstract float process();
}

abstract class BaseEdge<TNode>
    // THIS HERE IS THE PROBLEM
    where TNode : BaseNode
{
    TNode from;
    TNode to;

    public TNode To
    {
        get
        {
            return to;
        }
    }

    public TNode From
    {
        get
        {
            return from;
        }
    }

    public abstract float process();
}
```

@Marceln wanted to see a my existing implementation, so here it is. It's just the same thing without the generics.

```
abstract class Graph
{
    BaseNode root;
    List<BaseNode> nodes;
    List<BaseEdge> edges;

    public abstract float process();
}

abstract class BaseNode
{
    List<BaseEdge> inputs;

    public List<BaseEdge> Inputs
    {
        get
        {
            return inputs;
        }
    }

    public abstract float process();
}

abstract class BaseEdge
{
    BaseNode from;
    BaseNode to;

    public BaseNode To
    {
        get
        {
            return to;
        }
    }

    public BaseNode From
    {
        get
        {
            return from;
        }
    }

    public abstract float process();
}
```

Where an implementation of a Node might look like this:

```
class ImplementedNode : BaseNode
{
    public override float process()
    {
        foreach (ImplementedEdge edge in this.Inputs)
        {
            // Something
        }
    }

    public bool getImplementationSpecificInfo()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @marceln. Do you mean the existing solution? Or an example of implementation?

Comment: Whatever is easier for you. As long as the problem is present, an example would do fine.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being thick and not understanding @marceln, but I'm not entirely sure what extra information you're after. The problem is present in the included code, as the lines `where TEdge : BaseEdge` and `where TNode : BaseNode` are invalid because BaseEdge and BaseNode are generic types but cannot be used in the form `BaseNode<THIS_GENERIC_EDGE_TYPE>`.

Comment: I've now added a further example as @marceln requested.

Comment: Are you willing to "sacrifice" the TNode/TEdge constraints from BaseNode and BaseEdge? If yes, it is doable.

Comment: Would that then not add (almost) all of the casts back in and basically take me back to the pre-generic version @marceln? Derived classes would be able to use without casting, but in the actual implementation I have some methods in the base classes that would still need to cast again. I guess if nothing else can be worked out this is probably the way to go though. Maybe I can remove the constraints from just one of them...

Comment: Oh, I could probably make those base class methods generic themselves, that might solve that...

Comment: Added a sample in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are willing to loosen up the constraints on `BaseEdge` and `BaseNode` then you could do something like in the example below.

I have introduced the interfaces `INode` and `IEdge` just so whoever works with this isn't allowed to create concrete subclasses of `BaseEdge` and `BaseNode` with any type.

```
public interface INode
{

}

public interface IEdge
{

}

public abstract class Graph<TNode, TEdge>
    where TNode : BaseNode<TEdge>
    where TEdge : BaseEdge<TNode>
{
    public TNode Root { get; set; }
    public List<TNode> Nodes { get; set; }
    public List<TEdge> Edges { get; set; }
}

public abstract class BaseNode<TEdge> : INode where TEdge: IEdge
{
    List<TEdge> inputs;

    public List<TEdge> Inputs
    {
        get
        {
            return inputs;
        }
    }

    public abstract float process();
}

public abstract class BaseEdge<TNode> : IEdge where TNode: INode
{
    TNode from;
    TNode to;

    public TNode To
    {
        get
        {
            return to;
        }
    }

    public TNode From
    {
        get
        {
            return from;
        }
    }

    public abstract float process();
}


public class ConcreteNode : BaseNode<ConcreteEdge>
{
    public override float process()
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

public class ConcreteEdge : BaseEdge<ConcreteNode>
{
    public override float process()
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

public class ConcreteGraph : Graph<ConcreteNode, ConcreteEdge>
{

}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is probably pretty much the closest I'll get to a solution, although as I said in the comments above, this doesn't play particularly neatly with the fact that BaseNode and BaseEdge also contain methods, as they will still need to cast internally. I'm going to keep working on this for a bit myself, but unless I come up with something significantly better I'll accept this solution.

Comment: Duh, completely forgot about interfaces in the "heat of the moment". Hehe, that'll do nicely.

Comment: @fourpastmidnight If `BaseNode` and `BaseEdge` need to do stuff internally, then why don't you implement that per-node or per-edge processing in other classes and set them here as properties? So, take all node/edge dependent code outside of the base classes otherwise you'll probably end up with huge implementations that handle each or most type of concrete types.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that's probably actually the way to go. It can be done, but it means a much larger refactoring. It's probably going to be worth it in the long run. I had looked at interfaces but ruled them out because of the internal method problems. Thanks for all the help, and for pushing me towards the sensible but annoying conclusion. You too @fourpastmidnight. I'll accept this answer.

Comment: @NodeDear glad we could help you out!!

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

Another answer, which provides for some type safety.

```
public interface IGraph<TNode, TEdge>
    where TNode : INode
    where TEdge : IEdge
{
    TNode Root { get; set }
    List<TNode> Nodes { get; set; }
    List<TEdge> Edges { get; set; }
}

public interface INode
{
    List<IEdge> Edges { get; set; }
}

public interface INode<TEdge> where TEdge : IEdge
{
    List<TEdge> Edges { get; set; }
}

public interface IEdge
{
    INode To { get; set; }
    INode From { get; set; }
}

public interface IEdge<TNode> where TNode : INode
{
    TNode To { get; set; }
    TNode From { get; set; }
}



public class MyGraph : IGraph<MyNode, MyEdge>
{
    public MyGraph(MyNode root)
    {
        Root = root;
    }

    public MyNode Root { get; set; }
    public List<MyNode> Nodes { get; set; }
    public List<MyEdge> Edges { get; set; }
}

public class MyNode : INode<MyEdge>, INode
{
    public List<MyEdge> Edges { get; set; }

    List<IEdge> INode.Edges
    {
        get { return this.Edges; }
        set { this.Edges = value; }
    }
}

public class MyEdge : IEdge<MyNode>, IEdge
{
    public MyNode To { get; set; }
    public MyNode From { get; set; }

    INode IEdge.To
    {
        get { return this.To; }
        set { this.To = value; }
    }

    INode IEdge.From
    {
        get { return this.From; }
        set { this.From = value; }
    }
}
```

This gave me no compile errors.

**UPDATE**

This answer does not work. But, I'm leaving it here for the comments that appear with it.

---

@NodeDear, I think your original example had it correct when `Graph` was generic:

```
Graph<TNode, TEdge> where TNode : BaseNode<TEdge>, TEdge : BaseEdge<TNode>
```

In the example you provided for @marceln, the `Graph` class is not generic. Therefore, you'll have to do all kinds of casting. with the generic version though:

```
public abstract Graph<TNode, TEdge>
    where TNode : BaseNode<TEdge>
    where TEdge : BaseEdge<TNode>
{
    public TNode Root { get; set; }
    public List<TNode> Nodes { get; set; }
    public List<TEdge> Edges { get; set; }
}

public abstract BaseNode<TEdge> where TEdge : BaseEdge<BaseNode<TEdge>>
{
    public List<TEdge> Edges { get; set; }
}

public abstract BaseEdge<TNode> where TNode : BaseNode<BaseEdge<TNode>>
{
    public TNode To { get; set; }
    public TNode From { get; set; }
}


public class MyNode : BaseNode<TEdge> where TEdge : BaseEdge<MyNode>
{
    ...
}

public class MyEdge : BaseEdge<TNode> where TNode : BaseNode<MyEdge>
{
    ...
}

public class MyGraph : Graph<MyNode, MyEdge>
{
    ...
}

public MyGraph<MyNode, MyEdge> g = new MyGraph<MyNode, MyEdge>();
List<MyEdge> edges = g.Nodes[0].Edges;
MyNode toNode = g.Edges[0].To;
```

This allows any type derived from `Graph<TNode, TEdge>` to have strongly-typed nodes and edges, which is what the OP is looking for.

Comment: How would the definitions for `BaseEdge` and `BaseNode` look like?

Comment: @marceln Hehe, I'm looking at that in VS right now to make sure I have it right...and most importantly, that it compiles ;)

Comment: :) I think it would be great if it works. But I don't see how you can get around this `BaseEdge<TNode> where TNode : BaseNode<BaseEdge<TNode>>`. Also, you're missing the `class` keyword in the example.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm stuck with @marceln. I was hoping there might be some trick I wasn't aware of for this, but it's not looking promising.

Comment: You may be able to do something similar, but it would require reflection to get rid of the casting...but still, casting would be occurring under the covers. In the end, there must be a simpler solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution

```
 public interface IGraph<TNode, TEdge>
    where TNode : INode<TNode, TEdge>
    where TEdge : IEdge<TNode, TEdge>
{
    public IEnumerable<TNode> Nodes { get; }
    public IEnumerable<TEdge> Edges { get; }
}

public interface INode<TNode, TEdge>
    where TEdge : IEdge<TNode, TEdge> 
    where TNode : INode<TNode, TEdge>
{
    IEnumerable<TEdge> Edges { get; }
    IEnumerable<TNode> Neighbors { get; }
}


public interface IEdge<TNode, TEdge>
    where TEdge : IEdge<TNode, TEdge> 
    where TNode : INode<TNode, TEdge>
{
    TNode To { get; }
    TNode From { get; }
}

public class Graph : IGraph<Node, Edge>
{
    public IEnumerable<Node> Nodes { get; }
    public IEnumerable<Edge> Edges { get; }
}

public class Node : INode<Node, Edge>
{
    public IEnumerable<Edge> Edges { get; }
    public IEnumerable<Node> Neighbors { get; }
}

public class Edge : IEdge<Node, Edge>
{
    public Node To { get; }
    public Node From { get; }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).